# Adding data to from a database to the Index page of laravel 5.4

Tags: php, database, laravel-5

I am trying to create an adverts section on my landing page of a laravel 5.4 project using data from a database but it is not working.
in my welcome, I have added this lines of code

```
    foreach($adverts as $advert)   {         
                 $advert;
                }
```

I have then created a WelcomeController with the following code

```
    namespace App\Http\Controllers;
    use Illuminate\Support\Facades\DB;
    use Illuminate\Http\Request;

    class WelcomeController extends Controller
    {
/**
 * Create a new controller instance.
 *
 * @return void
 */
public function __construct()
 {
    $this->middleware('auth');
}

/**
 * Show the application dashboard.
 *
 * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
 */
public function index()
{
    $adverts = DB::table('adverts')->get();

    return view('welcome', ['adverts' => $adverts]);
   }
}
```

This gives me an error $adverts is not defined
What could I be doing wrong?

Comment: First check whats coming in $adverts with print_r($adverts); die; Also, echo is not there. add it. foreach($adverts as $advert)   {   echo $advert->id;  }

Comment: Have you created an `adverts` table?

Comment: Yes I have created it using the migrations file and added it to my database

Comment: blade's `foreach` should be `@foreach(...) ... @endforeach`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`$adverts is not defined` error is coming because you are missing `echo` or {{ $adverts->item }} in case of Laravel.

You need to echo `$adverts` data in `foreach` in your blade file in the below way:

```
@foreach($adverts as $advert)       
     {{ $advert->item }}
@endforeach
```

Or you can simply use PHP as well like below:

```
foreach($adverts as $advert){         
    echo $advert->item;
}
```

You can also convert your data to array and then display in foreach like below:

```
$adverts = DB::table('adverts')->get();
$adverts = json_decode( json_encode($adverts), true);

@foreach($adverts as $advert)         
    {{ $advert['item'] }}
@endforeach
```

You can first check what's coming in $advert array in the below way:

```
echo "<pre>"; print_r($adverts); die;
```

Comment: It is still giving me the same error.
Undefined variable: adverts (View: C:\wamp64\www\Vidic\resources\views\welcome.blade.php)

Comment: I have changed and used echo $advert->item; but that still gives the error $adverts not defined

Comment: First try echo "<pre>"; print_r($adverts); die; Add it before foreach.

Comment: I think the problem may be that the $advrets variable in the controller is not passed to the view. This I don't know how to do on the index page since it never has a controller

Comment: Show me your return view statement

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/160941/discussion-between-amit-gupta-and-otema).

Comment: That gives this output https://1drv.ms/i/s!AhlNVL0FlSDajAkNwU_lF_6zK4MX

Comment: it must be like return view('blade_file')->with(compact('adverts'));

Comment: add like this <?php echo "<pre>"; print_r($adverts); die; ?>